# Jhipster Context-path change

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have changed context path in my jHipster application, as documented by spring boot docs (prop: server.servlet.context-path: /mypath). However this made the jHipster generated UI unable to make API calls. So i tried to update app/app.constants.ts:

```
SERVER_API_URL = process.env.SERVER_API_URL + '/mypath';
```

but that made no difference. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of JHipster are you using (and Angular or React)?  Tested with JHipster v5.1.0 using Angular, set the `server.servlet.context-path` and it worked as expected

Comment: I am using jhipster 5.1 with angular. So just changing the context path should work, right? I mean the api works with the new context path. It is just the UI, which is unable to login a user after changing the context path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i found the solution. When you update context-path and you are using

```
yarn start
```

(to serve UI + proxy api calls), you also have to update webpack.dev.js -> context.
Example:

```
 context: [ '/api', '/auth'.....]
```

to something like this:

```
 context: [ '/myContextPath/api', '/myContextPath/auth'.....]
```

Also do not forget to include the context path in app/app.constants.ts as described in the question.

```
SERVER_API_URL = process.env.SERVER_API_URL + '/mypath';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it worked for me with just the addition in the webpack.dev.js. If I add the same in the app.constants file too then it comes twice in the URL.